# Sum Product Formula

Tags: excel, formula, sumproduct

I have 3 columns, A, B, and C. In column A is the product, column B is the order date, column C is the amount paid. I'm trying to find a sum product formula that will look for the total amount paid for the entries that match the Product and were ordered during a specific time period. Below is an example formula that I am trying to use:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT((V3:V1000=A2)*(R3:R1000,">=10/1/2021",R3:R1000,"<=10/31/2021")*(U3:U1000)
```

Comment: Why not just use a `SUMIFS` instead?

Comment: Dang, didn't think of it. Got it to work, thanks!